# alert wpf application when record inserted in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC and a WPF application, and basically I want to be able to alert the WPF application whenever a record is inserted in an SQL Database through the MVC application.

I am using EF and LINQ to do the CRUD in the MVC application, and the WPF is just a 'listener' retreiving the inserted records from the MVC app and displaying them on a GUI.

So what I would want to be able to do is get a popup alert in the MVC app once a record in the MVC app is inserted into the database.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wire something up using StreamInsight depending on what version of SQL you have but id just get the WPF app to poll the db for changes

Comment: I don't have much experience with WPF and Windows.  When you mean poll the db changes, you mean something like a Windows Service that is monitoring the CRUD in the database and alerting the WPF app?

Comment: YOu don't need a service - in the WPF app start a BackgroundWorker or a TPL task that runs a continuous loop (with a pause). ON every iteration of the loop check the db to see if there are any db changes and if there are report them back to the UI thread - id write you some code but im on my phone.

Comment: Ok so there is a BackgroundWorker that I am thinking works like a thread that will go and check the database for changes.  If you have any good tutorials, would be nice to point out.  Thanks Matt

Comment: Just like to add that this approach has a limit on scalability - i.e. if the WPF app will be open on lots of machines you might run into performance problems.  But it is architecturally the simplest approach.  Regarding tutorials, just google Thread Parallel Library.